# CanCan difference between :read and [:index, :show]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

According to all documentation, the `:read` action is aliased to both `:index` and `:show`:

```
alias_action :index, show, :to => :read
```

However, consider the following scenario with nested resources:

```
resources :posts
  resources :comments
end
```

If I define abilities like this:

```
# ability.rb
can :read, Post
can :show, Comment

# comments_controller.rb
load_and_authorize_resource :organization, :find_by => :permalink
load_and_authorize_resource :membership, :through => :organization
```

things work as expected. However, if I change the `:read` action to [:index, :show]:

```
# ability.rb
can [:index, :show], Post
can :show, Comment

# comments_controller.rb
load_and_authorize_resource :organization, :find_by => :permalink
load_and_authorize_resource :membership, :through => :organization
```

I am unauthorized to access `/posts/:post_id/comments`, `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id`, etc. I still, however, can access both `:index` and `:show` for the `posts_controller`.

How is possible that these actions are "aliased", if they behave differently?

In my fiddling, I also came across the following. Changing `load_and_authorize_resource` to the following allowed access:

```
# ability.rb
can [:index, :show], Post
can :show, Comment

# comments_controller.rb
load__resource :organization, :find_by => :permalink
load_and_authorize_resource :membership, :through => :organization
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I posted this as an issue on GitHub. Ryan responded with the following:

> Both the `:index` and `:show` actions
>   point to the `:read` action. But when
>   CanCan authorizes a parent resource it
>   uses the `:read` action directly which
>   is why you're seeing this behavior.
>
> I think this has caused confusion
>   before, so I will change the internal
>   behavior to never use the `:read`
>   action directly. Instead of a
>   `:parent` resource I'll change it to
>   use `:show` and for the
>   `accessible_by` default I will use
>   `:index` instead of `:read`. Thanks
>   for bringing this to my attention.

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/302#comment_863142