# Cancan ability triggering even though not calling it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using cancan and checking authorizing a user to go to the index page. However, an ability is triggering a cannot false positive. Here's what I have in my messages#index:

```
  def index
    authorize! :index, Message
    @messages = current_company.messages.most_recent.paginate(:page => params[:page]).includes([:user, :customer])
  end
```

and the ability causing the issue:

```
cannot :read, Message do |resource|
  !company.active? && company.last_state_change_at && resource.created_at > company.last_state_change_at
end
```

however this makes no sense since I'm not asking cancan to verify a :read, instead an :index. when I comment out that ability block, everything works fine. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:index` is same as `:read`

See

- https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/302#comment_863142 & -
- [CanCan difference between :read and [:index, :show]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280781/cancan-difference-between-read-and-index-show)

Comment: actually index is a subset of read, read maps to index and show, just to make it clear to other people.

Comment: That makes sense...however, since we aren't passing in an object, shouldn't it skip that block anyways?